# How to make function in typescript which gets called after specific time?

Tags: typescript, angular7

I need ti write a function in typescript (as i'm working on angular 7) which gets called on every five seconds on visiting the page for checking for new notifications but i don't know how to make this function can anybody help me in this regard?

Comment: setInterval should work in Typescript as well  setInterval (functionToCall:function,intervalInMilliSeconds:number,...args:any[])

Comment: ERROR in src/app/components/home/home.component.ts(27,19): error TS2345: Argument of type 'Subscription' is not assignable to parameter of type 'TimerHandler'.
  Type 'Subscription' is not assignable to type 'Function'.
    Property 'apply' is missing in type 'Subscription'.

Comment: for this error a bit more source code is necessary